# karma & jasmine & browserify state leaking?

Tags: karma-jasmine, vue.js

I have two karma tests (for vuejs) which work correctly if run on their own, but, if I run them as part of a suite, then one of them will fail.

I'm quite new to JS testing so I suspect there's an issue with imports being shared somehow?! though that does seem a bit odd.

Anyway, here are the two tests, if someone can explain why they don't work when run together I'd love to hear it.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import CastList from '../../../frontend/components/Cast-List.vue'

describe('CastList2.vue', () => {
  var vm;
  var component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    CastList.data = function () {
      return {
        initialFetchComplete: true,
        refreshable: true
      }
    };
    vm = new Vue({
      template: '<div><test v-ref:component></test></div>',
      components: { test: CastList }
    }).$mount();

    component = vm.$refs.component;
  })

  it('should have a refresh button', (done) => {
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('button[name=refresh]')).toBeTruthy();
    component.refreshable = false;
    component.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(vm.$el.querySelector('button[name=refresh]')).toBeFalsy();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

and...

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import CastList from '../../../frontend/components/Cast-List.vue'

describe('CastList.vue', () => {
  var vm;
  var component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    CastList.data = function () {
      return {
        initialFetchComplete: true,
        refreshable: false
      }
    };
    vm = new Vue({
      template: '<div><test v-ref:component></test></div>',
      components: { test: CastList }
    }).$mount();

    component = vm.$refs.component;
  })

  it('should have a refresh button', (done) => {
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('button[name=refresh]')).toBeFalsy();
    component.refreshable = true;
    component.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(vm.$el.querySelector('button[name=refresh]')).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

my karma.conf looks like this:

```
// https://github.com/Nikku/karma-browserify
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],
    files: ['spec/frontend/**/*.js'],
    reporters: ['spec'],
    preprocessors: {
      'spec/frontend/**/*.js': ['browserify']
    },
    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      // needed to enable mocks
      plugin: [require('proxyquireify').plugin]
    },
    // if you want to continuously re-run tests on file-save,
    // replace the following line with `autoWatch: true`
    singleRun: true
  })
}
```

I've named the two test files "Cast-List" and "Blah" and looking at the error message it does seem that the two files are conflicting.

```
1) should not have a refresh button
     CastList2.vue
     Expected null to be truthy.
/var/folders/tz/9v8nv4t92mq5np77n3tqgr_00000gn/T/057de4a9f4398d04398e527f6243d941.browserify:14898:68 <- spec/frontend/unit/Cast-List.spec.js:28:4
/var/folders/tz/9v8nv4t92mq5np77n3tqgr_00000gn/T/057de4a9f4398d04398e527f6243d941.browserify:14856:11 <- spec/frontend/unit/Blah.spec.js:28:6
/var/folders/tz/9v8nv4t92mq5np77n3tqgr_00000gn/T/057de4a9f4398d04398e527f6243d941.browserify:5218:14 <- node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js:470:0
nextTickHandler@/var/folders/tz/9v8nv4t92mq5np77n3tqgr_00000gn/T/057de4a9f4398d04398e527f6243d941.browserify:5193:16 <- node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js:445:0
```

I think the issue is that I'm being somewhat evil over-riding the imported `CastList` es6 module import, and [modules are live not copies](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change your describe to have a different name. When you put same describe name in two different files, it combines those two and so you are ending up with a conflict in beforeEach(because a describe can have only one beforeEach) and thus one of the test fails.

Comment: I renamed one of the describe blocks and it still fails. However, that's certainly where the issue lies, or at least, I think so from looking at part of the error message, I'll update the question with the failure.